# Shuttering image effect insertion

Tags: javascript, effects, image-effects

Can anybody tell me if I would like to use this effect on my website the JS code simply goes in the head of the HTML document? thx

https://codemyui.com/shattering-images/

Comment: i really don't know what you want. the solution is posted on the website you linked

Comment: did you try? You wont break the internet if you get it wrong :p

Comment: lol I tried before and din't work however I am gonna try now inserting in another website...I will let you know the outcome

Comment: Looks like from the link that it's built in Codepen (https://codepen.io/zadvorsky/pen/dILAG), you select "Export" in the bottom right of that page to get all the files.

Comment: I see now, thx for the link...I had a feeling that the js should go into an external file.